# Convert List of data.frames to a single data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I imported a bunch of spreadsheets into R as a list of dataframes using the XLConnect package and this:

```
    sheet_names <- getSheets(wb)
names(sheet_names) <- sheet_names
sheet_list <- lapply(sheet_names, function(.sheet){
  readWorksheet(object=wb, .sheet)})
```

I'm now trying to combine these data frames (each 134 observations by 8 variables) into a single data frame so that I can carry out some further analysis. I found this line of code which gets me some of the way there:

```
sh_combined <- do.call("cbind", sheet_list)
```

However this produces a data frame that is 134 obs by 203 variables where each of the 8 variables has been duplicated. Ideally my combined dataframe would have a variable 'name' which is the name of each original dataframe - n.b. in this case each of the 29 dataframes represents responses to a questionnaire that were answered by 20 different organisations.

I'm not really used to using Lists so can't figure out a convenient way to achieve this. The other problem is that the data was badly structured when it was first captured (formatted for excel) so is not exactly 'tidy'. The individual spreadsheets do all have consistent row and column names though.

The entire list is huge but here is the structure:

```
List of 29


$ Alliance Youth Group :'data.frame':   134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "192" "8" "20" "5" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 9600 3600 4800 250 NA NA 900 1000 1200 300 ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Bidii Kweli          :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "300" "0" "12" "5" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 60000 NA 960 600 NA NA 160 NA 240 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Bidiika              :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "82" "N/A" "12" "1" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 4592 NA 1800 400 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BigShip              :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "100" "104" "30" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 30000 31200 9000 NA 3500 NA 2100 17500 17500 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Bokole               :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "50" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 10000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 200 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Brilliant Minds      :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "20" "N/A" "5" "N/A" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 6000 NA 250 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Changing Ambassador  :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "300" "4" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 75000 600 0 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Chenda Investments   :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "No" "15" "20" "No" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] NA 27000 60000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Customer Segments    :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector        : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject       : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable      : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA     : chr [1:134] "12" "22" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Strems: num [1:134] 2400 39600 NA NA NA NA 150 NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes         : chr [1:134] NA "In almost all their apartments they are devided into 6 section/wings where each wing pays KES 300 per month" NA NA ...
 $ Driver Conductor     :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "138" "1" "4" "5" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 5520 200 200 250 100 NA NA 400 NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ District Scouts      :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "150" "No" "15" "20" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 79950 NA 2400 4800 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Ganjoni Youth        :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "150" "No" "8" "11" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 4500 NA 240 440 NA NA NA 300 100 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Grandi Youth Bunge   :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "630" "No" "50" "10" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Stream.: num [1:134] 151200 NA 12000 2400 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ King Orani Youth     :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "200" "20" "4" "2" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 40000 6000 1600 800 NA NA NA NA 400 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Magongo Santana      :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "10" "8" "6" "N/A" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 8800 1280 1200 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Mbuyuni Youth        :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "150" "0" "50" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 15000 NA 3000 NA NA 800 NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ More Flow Enterprises:'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "No" "409" "6" "No" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: chr [1:134] NA "349,000" NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] "Company signs contracts only with landlords/resident agents. Data concerning the value of these contracts is not currently avai"| __truncated__ NA NA NA ...
 $ Mukono Self Help     :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "40" "No" "6" "4" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 6000 NA 1200 600 NA NA NA 300 400 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Mombasa Youth Network:'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector        : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject       : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable      : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA     : chr [1:134] "No" "76" "No" "No" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Steams: num [1:134] NA 3800 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure: num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes         : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ OneWorld Youth       :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "50" "No" "15" "10" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 1000 NA 300 500 NA NA NA 20 NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structures: num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Quatet               :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "12" "22" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 2400 39600 NA NA NA NA 150 NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Safi Youth Group     :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "250" "700" "0" "0" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 25000 140000 NA NA NA NA NA 3500 NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sent Kumi Youth      :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "186" "4" "8" "4" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 18600 400 1280 480 NA NA NA 160 200 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Smart Guys           :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "100" "No" "No" "2" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 12000 NA NA 160 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Soweto Self Help     :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "100" "N/A" "1" "8" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 14000 NA 60 640 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Stretchers           :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "22" "No" "8" "4" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 2200 NA 800 200 NA NA NA 200 NA NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure.: num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Taka ni Mali         :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "396" "4" "8" "6" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 59400 4000 1600 2400 0 0 600 300 900 0 ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tuliza               :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "90" "3" "N/A" "2" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 16200 4500 NA 200 NA NA NA 400 400 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Stucture  : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] "The 18 households are single bedroom houses and they pay KES 100 per  month while the rest are double bedroom that pay KES 200 "| __truncated__ NA NA NA ...
 $ Zama Uzuke           :'data.frame':  134 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Sector         : chr [1:134] "Customer Segements" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Subject        : chr [1:134] "Waste Generators" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Variable       : chr [1:134] "Residential (Household)" "Residential (Apartment)" "Commercial (Dukas)" "Commercial (Bandas)" ...
  ..$ Yes.No.NA      : chr [1:134] "17" "12" "10" "No" ...
  ..$ Revenue.Streams: num [1:134] 4080 2400 2400 NA NA NA NA 1600 1600 NA ...
  ..$ Cost.Structure : num [1:134] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Notes          : chr [1:134] NA NA NA NA ...
```

I want my final dataframe to look something like this

Sector | Subject | Variable | Yes.No.NA | Revenue... | Cost... | Notes | Name*

*where name is a new variable that represents the name of the original dataframe.

N.B. 'Variable' is the key index here (there are 134 different variables).

Really hope this makes sense, and apologies if this has been answered elsewhere - I did try and find some answers elsewhere on SE.

Thanks

Marty

Comment: You probably want `do.call(rbind, sheet_list)`, not `cbind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first add the name with

```
sheet_list <- mapply(function(df, name) {
                           df$Name <- rep(name, nrow(df))
                           return(df)
                       }, df = sheet_list, name = names(sheet_list),
                          SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

then, put all your data.frames into a single one with

```
all_df <- do.call("rbind", sheet_list)
```

***Another option,*** you can also add the names after the call to `do.call`:

```
all_df <- do.call("rbind", sheet_list)
all_df$Name <- gsub("\\.\\d+$", "", row.names(all_df))
```

**Edit**
If all the data.frames' colnames are not the same, you can do, as a first step, (for example to give all data.frames the same colnames as the first data.frame):

```
sheet_list<-lapply(sheet_list, function(x) {colnames(x) <- colnames(sheet_list[[1]]) ; return(x)})
```

Comment: thanks for this. I've a feeling my data wasn't as uniform as I'd hoped though as `do.call("rbind", sheet_list)` gives me the error `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`. Does this mean the rownames are not the same across the different dataframes?

Comment: @marty_c, it's hard to tell exactly why you got the error (I don't remember having this error before) but you can do some "tests" on your data, like for example `lapply(sheet_list, function(x){all(colnames(x)==colnames(sheet_list[[1]]))})`. It seems indeed likely that all data.frames have not the same colnames. Also, you can chek the number of columns with `lapply(sheet_list, ncol)` to check wether all data.frames have the same number of columns (better do it before checking the colnames...)

Comment: Hmmm, I checked the column names in the original data frames and they all looked the same but when I try `lapply(sheet_list, function(x){all(colnames(x)==colnames(sheet_list[[1]]))})` I get about half TRUE and half FALSE. Is there anyway to set all of the column names the same as say the first dataframe...?

Comment: @marty_c, yes, you can add a colnames change in the `mapply` call, or do a `lapply` before `do.call` in the second option. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. If you have all data frames in an environment (e.g., global environment), you can grab all of them using `mget()` and create a list. Then, you can employ `unnest()` in the `tidyr` package; you can create a column with the names of your data frames with this function. I created a simple sample data and did the following. Hope this will help you.

```
Alliance <- data.frame(Sector = "Customer Segements",
                       Subject = "Waste Generators",
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


Bidii <- data.frame(Sector = "Customer Segements",
                    Subject = "Waste Generators",
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# I do not know what kind of patterns you have. You may need to adjust this part.
mylist <- mget(ls(pattern = "^.*"))

# mylist
#$Alliance
#              Sector          Subject
#1 Customer Segements Waste Generators
#
#$Bidii
#              Sector          Subject
#1 Customer Segements Waste Generators

library(tidyr)
unnest(mylist, names)

#     names             Sector          Subject
#1 Alliance Customer Segements Waste Generators
#2    Bidii Customer Segements Waste Generators
```